# 404 crawl error for mailto:info@mydoamin.co.uk in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, 404, mailto

I'm getting a 404 crawl error for `mailto:info@mydoamin.co.uk`, in Google webmaster tools under the health > crawl errors.

Surly Google should see that `mailto:` is related to an email not a webpage..

The HTML I'm using for the mailto on my page is `<a href="mailto:mailto:info@mydoamin.co.uk">info@mydoamin.co.uk</a>`

What's the best way to resolve this? Is mailto still widely used or is there a newer alternative ?

Comment: Old question that popped to the top: using mailto: links on a website is unwise unless you love spam.  Harvesters will grab your email address in no time and you will be added to countless lists.  Use a captcha protected contact form instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `mailto:` strings in that `href`.

Google may well be using a regex that doesn't match a colon after the first one before the @.  I don't know what Google are doing, but whatever they are doing it's not working with that `href`.  Normal clients may have troubles with it as well.

Comment: I suggest to use `<a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@example.com</a>`. `mailto:info@example.com` is not a valid e-mail address, `mailto:` is the protocol part.

Comment: sorry ive just looked at the actual site and its writen the way you've advised. the example about i changed it to hide the site and forgot to remove the second mailto part.. but i the actual live version where im getting the error it is as you've written. ill edit the question to make clear